# Jquery Datatables - custom filtering for last element of group of Ids with checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have data that looks like the following in a jquery datatable

```
Id      Revision
-----------------
123400 | 01
123401 | 04
123402 | 09
456789 | 00
456790 | 05
-----------------
```

Now the user needs a checkbox that filters the datatable to show only the last entry in the table of a group of Ids (grouped by first 4 characters).
This should be the result from filtering the above table

```
Id      Revision
-----------------
123402 | 09
456790 | 05
-----------------
```

The Ids are grouped by "1234" and "4567" and the last entries are displayed.

So i fetch all data that i get from the server, and build a new array that contains the data for the second table above:

```
var lastIndex;
    var lastRev;
    var newData = [];
    var n = 0;
    for (var k = 0; k < data.length; k++)
    {
        // if new ID is unknown and new Rev is unknown, fill newData and count up
        if (data[k][0].indexOf(lastIndex) < 0 && data[k][1].indexOf(lastRev) < 0) {
            newData[n] = data[k];
            n++;
        }
        else // else overwrite last element
        {
            newData[n - 1] = data[k];
        }

        lastIndex = data[k][0].substring(0, 4);
        lastRev = data[k][1];
    }
```

Now comes the part that doesn't work like expected

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(function (oSettings, aData, iDataIndex) {

        var checked = $('#myCheckbox').is(':checked');

        if (checked)
    {

            for (var i = 0; i < newData.length; i++)
            {                
                if ((aData[0] == newData[i][0]) && (aData[1] == newData[i][1]))
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }

        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

var oTable = $('#myTable').dataTable();
    $('#myCheckbox').on("click", function (e) {
        oTable.fnDraw();
    });
```

This only returns the first Element which is the Id "123402" with the Revision "09". 
But i was expecting it to display as it is shown in the second table above.

What am i doing wrong, or what am i missing here?
Any help would be appreciated

Thank you in advance,
Charly H.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem:** The problem is with this part of the logic.

```
      for (var i = 0; i < newData.length; i++)
        {                
            if ((aData[0] == newData[i][0]) && (aData[1] == newData[i][1]))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

**This has a return statement which will never go past the first iteration**. That is the reason you get only one row.

---

**Solution:** You must remove the `else` part in the `for` loop. Like below

```
      for (var i = 0; i < newData.length; i++)
        {                
            if ((aData[0] == newData[i][0]) && (aData[1] == newData[i][1]))
            {
                return true;  // if record found return true immediately;
            } 
            // if not found wait for next loop, we need to make sure we 
            //complete the loop before deciding the data not found.              
        }
        return false; // Now since we are out of the loop its obvious that 
                      //we didnt find the record.
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: Thank you, that worked like i was expecting. I just removed this part "&& (aData[1] == newData[i][1])" from the loop as this was causing my execution to leave the loop when the revision was equal as the last.